# Android, System login sending data (POST) says Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.

Tags: php, android, eclipse, authentication, request

I'm trying to create a login system with Android app in Eclipse.

The problem is that the compiler shows errors that I do not understand why.

```
package com.example.server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private Button login;
    private EditText username, password;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String   mUsername = username.getText().toString();
            String  mPassword = password.getText().toString();

            tryLogin(mUsername, mPassword);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

protected void tryLogin(String mUsername, String mPassword)
{           
    HttpURLConnection connection;
   OutputStreamWriter request = null;

        URL url = null;   
        String response = null;         
        String parameters = "username="+mUsername+"&password="+mPassword;   

        try
        {
            url = new URL("http://edonetwork.altervista.org/AndroidProject/validateLogin.php");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");    

            request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            request.write(parameters);
            request.flush();
            request.close();            
            String line = "";               
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            // Response from server after login process will be stored in response variable.                
            response = sb.toString();
            // You can perform UI operations here
            Toast.makeText(this,"Message from Server: \n"+ response, 0).show();             
            isr.close();
            reader.close();

        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            // Error
        }
}
}
```

Eclipse writes:

```
[2014-02-17 19:42:35 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
[2014-02-17 19:42:35 - Server] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
```

I can not understand where the problem is because the code above was taken from a tutorial to get started.

I found this tutorial, but someone can recommend the best methods for making requests to php page or even in real systems login?

Comment: it is problem with Eclipse not with your code,  try to restart IDE

Answer (score 0):

Please see this.

http://soda815.blogspot.in/2013/09/android-how-to-use-httpurlconnection-to.html
or
http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-http-with-asynctask-example/

Its an easy to understand and working example. Let me if this helps. Happy coding :)

Comment: Yes completely agree with you. My bad. @Edoardo - Please refer this one instead which makes use of Asynctask which will do the network request on a separate thread and will not block the UI. http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-http-with-asynctask-example/

Comment: and this one as well http://soda815.blogspot.in/2013/09/android-how-to-use-httpurlconnection-to.html

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me for the earlier goof up. @Selvin is correct as all the network operations should be done on a NON UI thread, and thus comes asynctask in picture.

Please refer [this](http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-http-with-asynctask-example/) and [this](http://soda815.blogspot.in/2013/09/android-how-to-use-httpurlconnection-to.html) to understand how asynctask works and achieve what you want with the POST method. Do let me know if you need any further explanation.